# Two DatePickers in one Activity

Tags: android, android-datepicker

In my activity I need 2 datepickers. Unfortunatelly I have no damn idea how to code this. I need them to be displayed as dialogs, due to lack of space.

Here's what I have and works for one DatePicker:

```
    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener)
                        getActivity(), year, month, day);

    }

}

 public void datePicker(View view) {
    DatePickerFragment fragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date");
}
```

and corresponding listener:

```
private void setDate(final Calendar calendar) {
    final DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);

    date = calendar.getTime();

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.date_text);

    dateString = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    btn.setText(dateString);
    }
```

now I would need a second listener for second fragment, but I have no idea how to implement it. (fragment only return dialog with already setup listener)\

**EDIT:**

I came up with idea, but the button text is set only after 2nd attempt:

```
public void datePicker2 (View view){

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,listener,year,month,day);

    dialog.show();



    listener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(i, i1, i2);
            setDateTo(cal);
        }
    };

}

 private void setDateTo(final Calendar calendar) {

    final DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);

    date = calendar.getTime();

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.date_to_text);

    dateString = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    btn.setText(dateString);

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to have two `DatePicker` widgets in one dialog? Or are you referring to having two separate `DatePickerDialogs`?

Comment: Two seperate DatePickerDialogs

Answer (score -1):

Move

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.date_to_text);
```

to onCreate